# How does await() and signal() work inside lock block?

Tags: java, multithreading

So for my own understanding, I wrote two threads each of which prints a line to output.
However, I wanted to make the two threads so that they print one after another. Let's say `t1` and `t2`. If `t1` prints its own message then it has to wait for the other thread to print theirs. Now I manage to make it working by experimenting but there is something I don't understand.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Multithread {
  
    public static void main(String [] m) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition c1 = lock.newCondition();
    
        Runnable t1 = new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i : new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}) {
                    lock.lock();
                    try {
                        c1.signal();
                        System.out.println("In thread 1 - " + i);
                        
                        try {
                            c1.await();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } finally {
                        c1.signal();
                        lock.unlock();
                    }
                }
                
            }
        };
        
        
        Callable<String> t2 = new Callable<String>() {

            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                for(int i : new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}) {
                    lock.lock();
                    try {
                        c1.signal();
                        System.out.println("In callable 2 - " + i);
                        try {
                            c1.await();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } finally {
                        c1.signal();
                        lock.unlock();
                    }
                }

                return "This is callable";
            }
            
        };
        
        new Thread(t1, "t1").start();
        FutureTask<String> task = new FutureTask<>(t2);
        new Thread(task, "t2").start();
        //c1.signalAll();
        System.out.println(task.get());
        
    }
}
```

Please ignore the code is used Callable and Runnable instead of using one type. So this is my interpretation of this code:

- Let's say t1 grabs the lock first, that means t2 is waiting for the lock to be released
- t1 `signal()`s other threads and then it prints its message and then it waits at `c1.await()`
- With this logic, t2 should never print its message because t1 is waiting and hasn't `unlock()` ed

But to my surprise, it works as I wanted to and each thread prints its message on a turn basis, that is:

- t1
- t2
- t1
- t2
- and so on

Another thing that I don't understand is the fact that `InterruptedException` never happens and the `printStackTrace()` never reached!

Can someone please explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

> With this logic, t2 should never print its message because t1 is waiting and hasn't unlock() ed

I think what you're missing is that `condition.await()` *unlocks* the `lock` from which `condition` was obtained, and then it guarantees to re-lock the `lock` before it returns.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks! So it unlocks the lock and the other thread (t2) grabs the lock and sends signal then t1 moves on to grab the lock next - in the meantime t2 prints its message. Is my understanding correct?